# Writing spark unit test without installing Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to write unit test for spark code. 
I know we can install Spark and then use SparkConf and SparkContext to write tests.

However, I wanted to check if there is any way we can write unit tests without installing Spark as my client don't want to install Spark on Jenkins server, where we intend to run our tests as part of automated process.

Comment: If you have a `Maven` project, you could add the dependencies. Then use the Spark API to create a new session and set master as `local`. The problem that you may face is the cost of creating a SparkContext in every Unit Test classes. It won't run in a few milliseconds.

Comment: We are using Python and Spark. Trying to run unit tests using Unittest framework. Are you sure we don't need to set SPARK_HOME or install Spark on Jenkins?

Comment: We are using Python, PySpark, Unittest and Spark. Are you sure to create SparkConf object we don't need SPARK_HOME set or Spark installed on Jenkins machine?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup Spark to run in a local cluster via code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster("local")
val context = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Then, you can use the `context` to create `RDDs` of your data for testing:

```
context.makeRDD
```

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#initializing-spark
- [What does setMaster `local[*]` mean in spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356143/what-does-setmaster-local-mean-in-spark)
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#makeRDD-scala.collection.Seq-int-scala.reflect.ClassTag-

Comment: We are using Python and Spark. Are you sure to create SparkConf object we don't need SPARK_HOME set or Spark installed on  Jenkins machine?

Comment: We are using Python, PySpark, Unittest and Spark. Are you sure to create SparkConf object we don't need SPARK_HOME set or Spark installed on Jenkins machine?

Comment: A quick search shows you can do this with PySpark as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811882/how-do-i-unit-test-pyspark-programs